# How to store data with Facebook.JsonObject or Facebook.JsonArray

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I use the FB C# sdk 5.2.from http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/
and develop with .net 3.5, so i cannot use the dynamic, and the var type is able to get the data, but the format is so ugly and hard to get the data i want.

I want to know how to store data with the Facebook.JSONObject or the JSonArray, it seems like there is no such a Dictionary["data"]function.
Besides, i cannot find the document

Any thoughts?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you need distionary try:

```
var fc = new FacebookClient("someAccessToken");
var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fc.Get("/me/feed");
```

or similar call.

Optionally give an example of what are you trying to retrieve and/or post?

Or you may use:

```
[DataContract]
public class PostCrate
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public List<Post> Data { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "paging")]
    public Paging Paging { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Paging
{
    [DataMember(Name = "previous")]
    public string Previous { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "next")]
    public string Next { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Post
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "from")]
    public BaseUser From { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "created_time")]
    public string CreatedTime { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "updated_time")]
    public string UpdatedTime { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class BaseUser
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var fc = new FacebookClient("someAccessToken"); 
var result = fc.Get<PostCrate>("/me/feed");
```

(any properties above can be omited)

DataMember names are base on 'keys' from IDictionary above

Comment: This works, but not convinient, you see, i just get a whole string, can not pick what i want, i want to have a Dictionary way to pick directly but not play with string class, since they already have the json class, but cannot find any examples, wired...

Answer (score 0):

```
[DataContract]
public sealed class Group
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "privacy")]
    public string Privacy { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer to provide more detail. Specifically, it would be helpful if you explained how this solves the problem